# Displaying nodes not meeting filter criteria in a network, using spring force layout and displaying text boxes on mouseover using cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I am new to cytoscape.js and was wondering whether it is possible to display nodes which do not meet my network filtering criteria searetely in the network i.e may be at the bottom of network as outliers. This would be very useful to enable the users to have a complete understanding of the network and how the filter criteria is being affected. For example like Figure A in http://www.plosone.org/article/fetchObject.action?uri=info:doi/10.1371/journal.pone.0004345.g005&representation=PNG_M

Also I would like to ask that I came across the springy layout option in cytoscape.js but it is not listed as in the main cytoscape.js. I am using the arbor layout at present and using the edge length parameter proportional to a data value. However, I want my edge lengths to be permanent (i.e, the network should spring back to original edge length if a node or edge is moved. Something like this - http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

Another query I have is regarding displaying toolboxes on mouseover. Is it possible to display a textbox with data details - like using tooltips in d3. I have seen this question in many places but didnt manage to find a working solution yet.

Thanks a lot for the very useful answers regarding cytoscape.js here!

Answer (score 0):

(1) It's up to you.  If you're using a force-directed layout, you can modify the forces for these elements, or you can programmatically set position, etc.

(2) Springy is not supported.  It doesn't have any advantages that I can see over Arbor -- Arbor is faster, gives better results, etc.  Running the layout all the time to maintain edge length is expensive, especially for large graphs.  You're better off locking the nodes after the layout is done so that they can't be moved.  It's better for performance, and it's better UI.  Having the nodes constantly move around makes the graph harder to keep track of elements and analyse.

If you play with Arbor's options you could potentially make the layout run forever (maybe end sim force of zero, no max sim time, etc.?), but I haven't tested this, nor is it the preferred option.

(3) You can use your preferred tooltip solution (e.g. Bootstrap, Qtip, etc.), specifying manual positioning to the element's position.  Maybe there will be a plugin for this eventually for a particular library like Qtip.  But for now, it's very simple to hook this together manually and this way you can use whichever library you prefer.

Note: You may want to separate your questions into different question pages on Stack Overflow next time.  This makes it easier to address each individual question, and it's better for other people who are reading who may not be interested in other questions.